# Finding specific HTML elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm trying to figure out this javascript library and what its doing.

```
self.o.selector = "[id^=landmarks] > *"
$(self.o.selector, this).each(function () {
```

So this will select all elements that follow the `self.o.selector` format in `this`

This would find the polygon elements in an SVG like so

```
<g id="landmarks-ground">
    <polygon fill="#91BF39" points="698.6,172 719.4,199.6 670.7,209.9 650.6,181.8   "/>
    <polygon fill="#91BF39" points="760.3,211.3 767.6,220.6 746.2,225.4 739.1,215.9     "/>
    ...
```

What can I make the selector code be so it selects polygons that are formatted like so?

```
<g>
    <g>
        <g class="st0">
            <g>
                <polygon class="st1" points="1052.2,287.8 1053.7,296.6 1040.5,304.1 1038.9,295.3                "/>
            </g>
            <g>
                <polygon class="st2" points="1052.2,287.8 1053.8,296.6 1052.6,300.4 1051,291.5              "/>
            </g>
            <g>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply select polygon tag into your class like this:

```
$('.st0 polygon').each(function(){
  //code
});
```

Comment: The class ranges from st0 to like st45, anyway to select all of those?

Comment: @EricG the selector `.st0 polygon[class^="st"]` wil match any `.st0 polygon` whose class begins by `st`

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me the most!

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer of Jules and the comment of Eric, the answer may be

```
$('g').is('[class^="st"]').find('polygon').each(function(){
  //code
});
```

Explanation:

- From any element "g"
- that has any class starting by "st"
- Select any element "polygon" that are inside

Answer (score 1):

Little ajustement to nicolallias,

```
$('g g').is('[class^="st"]').find('polygon').each(function({
   //code
});
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).is(...).find is not a function` Any idea?

Comment: `$('g g g[class^="st"] g').find('polygon')`